# This program requires version 3.2.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.6.1

Tags: python, pip, protocol-buffers, caffe, pycaffe

I'm trying to train a Caffe model. My .prototxt file uses custom Python Data and Loss layers.

When I execute the training command in terminal, however, this error is raised:

```
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:61] This program requires version 3.2.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.6.1.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc".)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
```

My Python Package Manager (pip) has version 3.2.0 of protobuf installed, but the system version is at 2.6.1 for a package called libprotoc. I am not sure how to specify that the pip protobuf version is the one I want to use for caffe.

On another computer which has version 3.3.0 of protobuf installed on pip and 2.6.1 for the system version, I was thrown the same error, except that it said the program required version 3.3.0 rather than version 3.2.0.

Best.

Comment: We need more information. How many different versions of Python do you have? Do you use virtual environments? What exctly does it mean "My Python Package Manager (pip) has version 3.2.0 of protobuf installed"? Which python (if you have more that 1 Pythons)?

Comment: im running in a docker conrainer with python 2.7. however on the other computer, i ran on a linux, no virtual container and still got the error so i do not believe thē error has to do with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into exactly the same issue today. The workaround that worked for me was to start the training from caffe's python interface as opposed to starting it directly from the shell. Example:

```
import caffe

weights = '../ilsvrc-nets/vgg16-fcn.caffemodel'
caffe.set_device(0)
caffe.set_mode_gpu()

solver = caffe.SGDSolver('solver.prototxt')
solver.net.copy_from(weights)

for _ in range(25):
    solver.step(4000)
```

Off course the above is just an example/very barebones, you'll have to handle running against the validation set yourself but the pycaffe interface is quite flexible and allows you to do all that. You can find more details on how to use that here:

http://christopher5106.github.io/deep/learning/2015/09/04/Deep-learning-tutorial-on-Caffe-Technology.html

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, i will give it a shot when i get back to work and report here with the result.

Comment: no probs. By the way, the above will also handle running against the test set (so you **don't** actually need to do it yourself) if you've set it up in your solver file. A simpler way to do it if you don't actually need the fine grained control of the for loop there, is to simply do `solver.solve()`.

Comment: Hi Kosta, your solution worked for me as well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I went around it by installing the same version of protobuf via pip, as the one from apt-get.

`pip install protobuf==2.6`

Alternative (which I wanted to avoid) was to install protobuf from sources.

https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md